# Delete all records except latest 5

Tags: mysql

I would like to delete all records except the newest 5 records (ordered by id).
I have the table "chat", and it contains records documented by "time".
How can I do it with 1 query?

Thank you very much.

Comment: delete has an order by and limit. In the right setting you could find the count use that info accordingly. You could use events to handle this for you, or triggers. Put on your thinking cap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply delete using `IN()` and `LIMIT` :

```
DELETE FROM YourTable 
WHERE ID NOT IN(SELECT id FROM YourTable
                ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5)
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '9999999999' at line 1